# myBatis Many To Many Relationship

Tags: java, sql, mapping, mybatis

In relation to my previous question regarding Mappings in MyBatis, I am now encountering a problem when doing a Many-To-Many relationship

I have the following objects

*I cannot post the actual object definition and XML due to privacy issues*

```java
class ObjectA {
     List<Items> items;
     List<Products> products;

     //getters setters
}

class Items {
   int id;
   String description;
   List<Tags> tags;
}

class Tags {
    int id;
    int item_id;
    String tag;
}
```

The SQL involves joining the Items table with Tags table `ON Tags.ITEM_ID = Items.ID`

Basically, it returns rows and maps them to this MyBatis

```xml
<resultMap id="getObjectA" type="ObjectA">
    <collection property="items" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Items" resultMap="getItems"/>
     
     ...

</resultMap>

<resultMap="getItems" type="Items">
    <id property="id" column="ITEMS.id"/>
    <result property="description" column="ITEMS.description"/>
    <collection property="tags" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Tags" resultMap="getTags"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="getTags" type="Tags">
   <id property="id" column="TAGS.id"/>
   <result property="item_id" column="TAGS.item_id"/>
   <result property="tag" column="TAGS.tag"/>
</resultMap>
```

Technically, the set up works and returns an ObjectA containing a List of Items each containing a List of Tags. When there exists only one Tag per Items, the mapping is fine but when an Item contains multiple Tags, it creates multiple Items of the same ID each containing a List containing only one Tag from the result of the query.

Comment: What's the SQL? Need to make sure the rows are orderded by the relevant IDs. MyBatis uses the IDs to identify (and not to repeat) items.

Comment: @TheImpaler the SQL uses aliases, proper labels for each columns are observed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that duplicates for parent objects are created means that mybatis cannot identify objects correctly, that is that `<id property="id" column="ITEMS.id"/>` does not work as expected. Basically `id` element is needed so that mybatis knows that the parent record that is duplicated in multiple rows in a result set refers to the same object.

One working option is to make sure columns from different tables have unique names and use that unique names in result map.

For your example mapper should look like this:

```xml
<resultMap type="ObjectA" id="objectaMap">
    <id column="id" property="id"/>
    <collection property="items" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Items" columnPrefix="ITEM_">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <result property="description" column="description"/>
        <collection property="tags" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Tags" columnPrefix="TAG_">
            <id column="id" property="id"/>
            <result property="tag" column="tag"/>
        </collection>
    </collection>
</resultMap>

<select id="getObjects" resultMap="objectaMap">
    select o.*, i.id as ITEM_ID, i.description as ITEM_DESCRIPTION, t.id as ITEM_TAG_ID, t.tag as ITEM_TAG_TAG
    from objecta o
        join items i on (i.object_id = o.id) 
        join tags t on (t.item_id = i.id)
</select>
```

Note how all columns from `items` table have `ITEM_` prefix and the same for `tags` table.

Comment: I am using aliases on the tables, I just wasn't able to include it here. I am successfully retrieving values, it's just that instead of Items having multiple Tags, it creates multiple Items with single Tags

Comment: The problem I'm getting is that instead of having a List of children objects, it creates duplicates of the parent object with individual children objects

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the query. The option I described in the answer works and creates single `Item` with the list of `Tag`s.

Comment: Yes, it works that way, but the problem is, ObjectA has no Id. It's just supposed to be an object containing a List of Items and List of Products. My resultMap returns ObjectA containing a Collection of Items and Products from the Select Query. We have the same query except that there is not supposed to be result of ObjectA rather than the join of Items, Tags, Products

Comment: Here in the comment you describe a new problem it seems. Its better to ask a new question with the details.